JOOQ "Partition By" Parsing Functionality
When parsing Postgres CREATE DDL Command using JOOQ.
Is there a way of parsing “Partition By” key word. Currently, it will throw exception if there is Partition By keyword.
I am wondering if it is a feature that is going to come out soon or there is any workaround on this that I missed.
I am using JOOQ 3.16.10.
An example of the Postgres SQL Schema would be something like:
CREATE TABLE people (
      id UUID NOT NULL,
      firstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'John',
      lastName VARCHAR(255),
      age integer[] NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT uk UNIQUE (id, firstName),
      CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
) Partition By RANGE (age);


As of jOOQ 3.19, this isn't supported yet, see:

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7844

You can comment out the PARTITION BY clause either completely, or using jOOQ's special parser "ignore-comment syntax", if the clause doesn't really matter to your specific jOOQ parser use-case:
CREATE TABLE people (
      id UUID NOT NULL,
      firstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'John',
      lastName VARCHAR(255),
      age integer[] NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT uk UNIQUE (id, firstName),
      CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 
/* [jooq ignore start] */
PARTITION BY RANGE (age)
/* [jooq ignore stop] */
;

This way, the clause continues to work in PostgreSQL, but jOOQ's parser will not see it

Should .withParseUnsupportedSyntax(IGNORE) setting bypass the error with "PARTITION BY"? Currently, it still throw errors.

@ninghaohe: No, that particular flag won't help you here in this case.
